# Sampling Anti-Aliasing Filter Bandwidth

Tags: sampling, aliasing

if i'm using Sampling frequency less than Nyquist Sampling frequency, Aliasing will occur which will scramble the whole signal, so one solution is to use anti-aliasing filter

How can i calculate it's Bandwidth, also is it a band-pass filter ?

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing occurs if there are signals present that are greater than half the frequency of the sampling frequency. Lower picture shows aliasing. Upper picture is OK: -

[image]

Using a filter to eradicate those frequencies is impossible because you would need a brick wall filter so you have to decide on how much attenuation you have to provide in the filter to give an acceptably low level of aliasing.

It's a low pass filter that reduces aliasing.

So decide on the attenuation required for any aliased signals and design a filter based on (typically) multiple sections of Sallen Key filters together forming (typically) a butterworth (maximally flat) low pass filter.

Comment: So if using fs lower than double the fm frequency it's impossible to recover the signal, the only way is to reduce this effect?

Comment: Correct @JenuRudan

Comment: ... unless you are intentionally doing bandpass sampling. fs must be at least double the **bandwidth** you are trying to read. It's just that because overwhelmingly most people want to sample from DC, that we usually say that fs has to be >twice the highest input frequency. You can use a bandpass filter, around a narrowband signal, and sample at much less than its centre frequency, as long as you sample at >2x its bandwidth. It's called 'High IF' sampling.

Comment: @Neil_UK good point - in effect you can regard "aliasing artefacts" as being pushed down below the lower bandwidth limit of your desired signal i.e. they can be rejected without loss of desired signal integrity.